# AWS::AppSync::Resolver using javascript in CloudFormation .yml fails to build

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql, yaml, aws-appsync-resolver

I'm having problems creating an AWS::AppSync::Resolver that is a PIPELINE kind, written in JavaScript. I think that the problem lies in what i write for `Code:` since in AWS docs it is not explained to details it only says that it is of type String. So i went with the assumption that it is the same as if i were to write code using VTL so i put the JS code directly into the .yml file for `Code:` parameter.

```
UpsertMappingDataResolver:
  Type: AWS::AppSync::Resolver
  Properties:
    ApiId: !GetAtt GraphQLApi.ApiId
    TypeName: "Mutation"
    FieldName: "upsertDataWithMapping"
    Kind: PIPELINE
    Code: "export function request(ctx) {
        return {
            foo: 'bar'
        };
    }
    
    export function response(ctx) {
        if(ctx.prev.result) return 1;
        return 0;
    }"
    Runtime:
      Name: APPSYNC_JS
      RuntimeVersion: "1.0.0"
    PipelineConfig:
      Functions:
        - !GetAtt UpsertItem.FunctionId
        - !GetAtt UpsertIntegrationMappingItem.FunctionId
  DependsOn:
    - Schema
```

So i tried this, but the CloudFormation build failed with the following this error:
The code contains one or more errors. (Service: AWSAppSync; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 0245d64d-...; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the meantime, it looks like the APPSYNC_JS runtime does not support arrow functions, and in my original code I had a forEach(()=>{}) method which was why my code was crashing.

Comment: Hello @JovanKecojevic, can you share your aws::AppSync::functionconfiguration code as in my pipeline config I have define that function, so I have code block in that function, and it’s giving me an same error as yours the code contains one or more error

Comment: I have created one JavaScript resolver js which contains resolver code, I have take reference for that code from aws docs, but it’s still having same as code contains one or more error. I have Checked everything that it’s not containing arrow or foreach like that. It’s driving me nuts.

Comment: I have asked same question here if you can look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422633/awsappsyncfunctionconfiguration-cloudformation-error-using-javascript-resolve

Answer (score 0):

Your code block is missing a YAML [multi-line code indicator](https://yaml-multiline.info) (e.g. `|`):

```yaml
Code: |
    export function request(ctx) {
        return {
            foo: 'bar'
        };
    }

    export function response(ctx) {
        if(ctx.prev.result) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: can you please look into this question and suggest possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422633/awsappsyncfunctionconfiguration-cloudformation-error-using-javascript-resolve